# Change permission in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, impex, hybris-data-hub

I have a group of users to whom I have to assign permission to use bulk edit, currently when I select a product, buld edit in listviewaction is disabled, I want to make it clickable for a certain group of users.
How I do this?
Thanks a lot.
Group of user that must have permission for bulkedit : "SiteManagerGroup"

```
<context component="listviewactions" parent="auto" principal="SiteManagerRole">
        <y:actions xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
            <y:group qualifier="common" show-group-header="false">
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.action.create" property="pageable.typeCode" />
                <y:action action-id="my.ext.path.backoffice.actions.familydeleteaction" property="selectedObjects" />
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.sync" property="selectedObjects" />
            </y:group>
            <y:group qualifier="bulk" show-group-header="false">
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.action.message" property="selectedObjects" triggerOnKeys="^c">
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>actionName</y:name>
                        <y:value>label.compareview.action.compareitems</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>message</y:name>
                        <y:value>#root</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>socket</y:name>
                        <y:value>selectedItemsToCompare</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>enabled</y:name>
                        <y:value>#root?.size() > 1</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>iconUri</y:name>
                        <y:value>/widgetClasspathResource/widgets/compare/images/Compare_default.png</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>iconHoverUri</y:name>
                        <y:value>/widgetClasspathResource/widgets/compare/images/Compare_hover.png</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>iconDisabledUri</y:name>
                        <y:value>/widgetClasspathResource/widgets/compare/images/Compare_inactive.png</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                </y:action>
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.bulkedit" property="selectedObjects" />
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.enumeration" property="selectedObjects">
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>qualifier</y:name>
                        <y:value>approvalStatus</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>actionName</y:name>
                        <y:value>bulk.approval</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                </y:action>
            </y:group>
            <y:extended-group qualifier="export" show-group-header="false">
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.excel.export" property="pageable.typeCode"/>
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.excel.exporttemplate" property="pageable.typeCode"/>
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.listview.action.export.csv" property="exportColumnsAndData">
                    <y:parameter>
                        <y:name>actionName</y:name>
                        <y:value>label.export.csv</y:value>
                    </y:parameter>
                </y:action>
                <y:extended-action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.excel.export"/>
            </y:extended-group>
            <y:group qualifier="import" show-group-header="false" show-separator="false">
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.excel.import" property="pageable.typeCode"/>
            </y:group>
        </y:actions>
    </context>

    <context component="customlistviewactions" parent="auto">
        <y:actions xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
            <y:group qualifier="common">
                <y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.bulkedit" property="selectedObjects" />
            </y:group>
        </y:actions>
    </context>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make a UserGroup instance an and assign usergroup to all users and run below Impex accordingly.

```
$START_USERRIGHTS; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
##
## 
##
Type           ; UID               ; MemberOfGroups ; Password ; Target                     ; read ; change ; create ; remove ; change_perm
BackofficeRole ; <<Custom_UserGroup>>   ;                ;          ;                            ;      ;        ;        ;        ;
               ;                   ;                ;          ; <<Custom Item Type>>      ; +    ; +      ; +      ; +      ; -

$END_USERRIGHTS; ; ; ; ;
```

Comment: didn't work, bulk edit can't be clickable yet.

Comment: please update the question with the image, it will give some hints for others.

Comment: entity is Product

Comment: which version of hybris are you using

Comment: version is   1905.22

Comment: Hi, some update?